# Routing issue with Laravel 4 and AngularJS in html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, angularjs-routing

I am creating a RESTful application with Laravel 4 as backend and AngularJS as frontend. I want to use routing from Angular.

`routes.php` in laravel are set up like this (with one group /api, but it is not necessary)

```
Route::any('{all}', function ($uri) {
    return View::make('index');
})->where('all', '.*');
```

My routes in Angular are

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/test/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I defined `<base href="/"/>` in `index.php`

And my DocumentRoot in xampp is in `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"` (so public folder in Laravel)

When I hit `localhost/test` everything works fine. But when I try access to `localhost/test/1`, everything is loaded as `index.php` file from Laravel views as you can see bellow.

[image]

Does anyone solve this problem? Should I create regex in `routes.php`, which will hold every (.js, .jpg, ...) extensions (i think it is not good idea)? Or should I change `.htaccess` file?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode.  Laravel isn't specifically listed, but you should be able to get an idea of how to configure it based on the other examples.

Comment: @Claies, it is not problem in `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` (i commented it out with same result), i think.

Comment: also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357258/angularjs-and-laravel-4-routing-conflict-in-html5-mode?rq=1

Comment: true, it's not a problem of `$locationProvider` specifically, it's a problem with the way your server is parsing requests.  But the correct configuration for a server is shown in those examples.

Comment: i.e. don't use `Route::any('{all}'` for angular, use `App::missing` instead.

Comment: I read every answer from that question before and the correct one was last, which I did not try http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304640/3937482. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357258/angularjs-and-laravel-4-routing-conflict-in-html5-mode/30304640#30304640) and changed missing routes catching in Laravel to this one and everything is fine.

```
App::missing(function ($exception) {
    return Redirect::to('/#/' . Request::path());
});
```

The problems were

- Angular in html5Mode need `#` as a prefix.
- Laravel was returning main page in subroutes including assets as I showed in the question.